# Using C2DM with .net 

Tags: android, .net, android-c2dm

1. Server authenticates against google client login to use app engine's C2DM server.  I understand that. I will use .net here. When data changes, I will send push notification to client and client service will refresh the data in their device db and UI will be updated. I am expecting this way the whole thing will work
2. All clients needs to register to server for receiving C2DM calls. Here there are interesting scenarios.
3. In my app there is a login in order to manage authentication and authorization to filter out the data that is relevant to him only. so at the same time I have to register to C2DM server as well. Is that correct?

> Let's take an example of task which is assigned to some user. If the
>   task is updated by user, it show send C2DM message to it's owner, and
>   it owner creates task it should send C2DM message to user who is
>   responsible for the task.

Is this practically possible? Is anything that I am missing or understanding wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is practically possible, but remember

1. you can send only limited data in your payload.
2. you have to write all logics inside your app to change UI.
3. Payload message data can only pin the decision making process.